# How to remove or hide archive page?

Tags: archives

How can I remove or hide this type of result after searching on my website

This page shows a full page product after searching

https://vipfash.com/?s=calvin+klein

Is this archive page ?

Thanks

Comment: this is a search result page

Comment: What do you want? To hide un-relevant results?

Comment: I didn't explain correctly, when I search  for products, products are too big width="385",heigh="500" , I want products dimensions like the other part of website heigh="275" , width="212"